# Include external script after dom has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this script thats including an ad, now I'm trying to include it after the dom has loaded.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.yashi.com/xxxx'></script>
```

the following was not working for me

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $( document ).ready(function() {   
    $.getScript("http://ads.yashi.com/xxxx");
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $.getScript("http://ads.yashi.com/xxxx");
};
```

Also did you check in your Network tab (either Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools), to see if it tries to load the script and succeeds?

Also, if you are trying to do something AFTER the script is loaded, you need to include a callback function:

```
$.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // do something now
});
```